# webpack multiple input files and multiple output files

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I'm creating a non-SPA website and wanted to use webpack, but I can't achieve situation when I have multiple input files and multiple output files. 
My input files has structure:

`-/front
  -app.js
  -/js
   -main.js
   -login.js`

and I want output to be:

`-/web
  -/bundles
   -main.js
   -login.js`

here's  beginning of my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve('src/front'), // main webpack folder
    entry: ["./app.js"],
    output: {
        filename: "./web/bundles/[name].js"
    },
```

Is it even achievable?

Now, only all required files in app.js are bundles under the name main.js in /web/bundles folder. How to change it?

Answer (score 10):

Use multiple entry points like this:

```js
entry: {
  app: './app',
  main: './js/main.js',
  login: './js/login.js',
},
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, './public'),
  filename: '[name].js'
},
```

Comment: ok, but when I'll add more files, I will have to update config all the time. Isn't there is something like gulp's expressions like '**/*.js' ?

Comment: This question is solved seems you have success. And whilecard is another question you can read about it [there](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/370) or ask new question. I hope you will have success.